# jquery - autocomplete with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysqli

I try to autocomplete a searchfield with jQuery-UI and I have problems using a PHP as source. Everything works fine when I use a variable as source.

JS:

```
$(function () {
    var data = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
    $("#tags").autocomplete({
        source: data
    });
});
```

But as soon as I use a PHP script, even if it just holds an array and encode it, it doesnt.

JS:

```
$(function () {
    $("#tags").autocomplete({
        source: 'suggest_search.php'
    });
});
```

suggest_search.php:

```
$data = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
echo json_encode($data);
```

I just cant figure out why, any suggestions?

EDIT: So the original problem is solved and was just a linking problem.

Now i want to get the data from SQL, but i cant figure out where i make the mistake again..

my phpcode:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
include(scripts/db_connect.php);
$searchTerm = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'term');
$select = mysqli_query($db_mysqli, " SELECT * FROM $db_table WHERE top_name like '%$searchTerm%'");
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($select)) 
{
 $data[] = $row['top_name'];
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

and the relevant html code:

```
<div id="ui-widget">
                    <label for="tags"></label>
                    <input id="tags" class="search_field" type="search" name="suche" maxlength="255">
</div>
```

Comment: Can you try an ajax call and see what it returns that way? maybe even save the ajax result to a variable

Answer (score 0):

It is not that simple, and I'm sincerely don't know why, but when you bind to a local array, a simple array works, but if you bind to a remote source, you need to give a result of an array of objects of this structure:

```
{
    "id":"Tetrao tetrix",
    "label":"Black Grouse",
    "value":"Black Grouse"
}
```

Check out this result I have taken from [this page](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote):

https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/autocomplete/search.php?term=rou

So your result should match that structure in order to work since I could not find anything related to the data structure in the [api docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source).

Comment: isnt json_encode() doing this? converting my array into that structure?

Comment: @whatever.idc of course not. How it would know the correct structure. Also, your array is just a simple array. You need an array of objects(classes).

Answer (score 0):

You have to use JSON header in your data source file.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$data = [
  "ActionScript",
  "AppleScript",
  "Asp",
  "BASIC"
];
echo json_encode($data);
```

HTML file content;

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
</head>
<body>

  <input id="tags">

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
     $(function() {
        $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
           source: 'json.php' 
        });
     });
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for reminding me to use the console. The problem was that i gave the path of the sourcefile realative to the js-file. That was wrong - i have to give it relative to the html-file :/